# java jaxb simple parsing is requiring @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, jaxb2

I am trying to parse an xml to java objects, I've read and implemented the following tutorial:

**http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html (works perfectly)**

But when I create my own clases (similar to those in the tutorial)

I get: Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
**Class has two properties of the same name "clienteList"**

Unless I use @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) on class Clientes but in the tutorial is not being used.

Any ideas ?

(It works fine with the @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation but I want to know why is it being required with my classes while it is not for the classes in the tutorial)

Thank you in advance for any information.

Class Cliente

```
package mx.com.findep.crediseguros.dto.servicios.finsol;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente {

  private String numeroPersona;

  @XmlElement(name = "numeroPersona")
  public String getNumeroPersona() {
    return numeroPersona;
  }

  public void setNumeroPersona(String numeroPersona) {
    this.numeroPersona = numeroPersona;
  }

}
```

Class Clientes

```
package mx.com.findep.crediseguros.dto.servicios.finsol;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "clientes")
//@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) //without this line it fails
public class Clientes {

      // XmLElementWrapper generates a wrapper element around XML representation
      @XmlElementWrapper(name = "clienteList")
      // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
      @XmlElement(name = "cliente")
      private ArrayList<Cliente> clienteList;


      public void setClienteList(ArrayList<Cliente> clienteList) {
        this.clienteList = clienteList;
      }

      public ArrayList<Cliente> getClienteList() {
        return clienteList;
      }


    }
```

Testing My Marshalling

```
package mx.com.findep.crediseguros.dto.servicios.finsol;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;


public class TestClientesXml {

  private static final String SOME_XML = "C:/bea/user_projects/domains/DominioDesarrollo/esquemas/calculoCostoSeguroPeticion.xml";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {

    ArrayList<Cliente> clienteList = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente();
    cliente1.setNumeroPersona("1");

    clienteList.add(cliente1);

    Cliente cliente2 = new Cliente();
    cliente2.setNumeroPersona("2");
    clienteList.add(cliente2);

    Clientes clientes = new Clientes();

    clientes.setClienteList(clienteList);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Clientes.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    m.marshal(clientes, System.out);

    m.marshal(clientes, new File(SOME_XML));

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Output from our XML File: ");
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Clientes clientes2 = (Clientes) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(SOME_XML));
    ArrayList<Cliente> list = clientes2.getClienteList();
    for (Cliente cliente : list) {
      System.out.println("Cliente: " + cliente.getNumeroPersona());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default JAXB treats public fields and properties as mapped.  If you annotate a field it then considers the field and property as mapped causing the conflict.  Without `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` you should annotate the get or set method.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: But in the example of the tutorial (of the link) is in the exact same way my code is, and it doesn't have the annotation isn't it?

Comment: @code4jhon - It's because in the example the list property has a getter but no setter.  This means that by default JAXB won't treat it as mapped.

Comment: That was driving me crazy, thank you very much, only that is does has a setter and but no getter. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without annotations?

Answer (score 0):

So lets say we have:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @XmlElement(name = "book_title")
    private String title;
    public getTitle(){..}
    public setTitle(){...}
    }
```

if we run the code we will have
Exception in thread "main"

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "title"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.example.jaxb.Book.getTitle()
        at com.example.jaxb.Book
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String com.example.jaxb.Book.title
        at com.example.jaxb.Book
```

But if we add the annotation: **XmlAccessorType**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Book {
```

the error will disappear.

When have class which want to marshall and have 10 fields, I prefer to annotate only fields, not one time the setter then the getter. So use @XmlAccessorType and annotate only the fields.