# Block specific domain (qaru.site) from google search results

Tags: plagiarism-detection

recently I started seeing results from qaru.site in the first 10 search results in google. This is kinda annoying as I hate plagiarism and it's just machine translated questions from StackOverflow, e.g.

[java jaxb simple parsing is requiring @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821896/java-jaxb-simple-parsing-is-requiring-xmlaccessortypexmlaccesstype-field-anno/35379427#35379427)

and

http://qaru.site/questions/2080946/java-jaxb-simple-parsing-is-requiring-xmlaccessortypexmlaccesstypefield-annotation

So, I have two questions:

1. Is that legal at all? If not can we do something against that?
2. Can I somehow ban this domain at least from my search results?

Sry, if it should be in some other part of StackExchange, I was guiding by domain used in questions.

Comment: StackOverflow content is CCBYSA, so translating it is certainly allowed. And perhaps your question should go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The second question would be on-topic on https://superuser.com/ The first one was already asked on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377579/7851470 and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846/378331